# Почему не работает программа ? Данная программа предназначена для вывода значений уровня владения иностранным языком на консоль с помощью Enum

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace learnCS.orgProjectEnum2
{
    class Program
    {
        enum People
        {
            Reed = 2,
            Hamilton = 2,
            Hart = 2,
            Pachev = 1,
            MacGhee = 2,
            Soucie = 2,
            Wilson = 2,
            Veehar = 2,
            Jack = 2,
            Schaumann = 1,
            Potter = 2,
            Slocumbe = 2,
            Innes = 2,
            Catlieb = 2,
            Clifford = 2,
            Eller = 0,
            Martindale = 1,
            Walch = 2,
            Thomson = 2,
            Flake = 2,
            Garner = 2,
            Pincoock = 2,
            Olson = 2,
            Galmeister = 0,
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string print = "'s Russian fluency rate is ";

            People eCatlieb;
            eCatlieb = People.Catlieb;
            Console.WriteLine(eCatlieb + print + ((int)eCatlieb));

            People eClifford;
            eClifford = People.Clifford;
            Console.WriteLine(eClifford + print + ((int)eClifford));

            People eEller;
            eEller = People.Eller;
            Console.WriteLine(eEller + print + ((int)eEller));

            People sFlake;
            sFlake = People.Flake;
            Console.WriteLine(sFlake + print + ((int)sFlake));

            People eGalmeister;
            eGalmeister = People.Galmeister;
            Console.WriteLine(eGalmeister + print + ((int)eGalmeister));

            People sGarner;
            sGarner = People.Garner;
            Console.WriteLine(sGarner + print + ((int)sGarner));

            People eHamilton;
            eHamilton = People.Hamilton;
            Console.WriteLine(eHamilton + print + ((int)eHamilton));

            People eHart;
            eHart = People.Hart;
            Console.WriteLine(eHart + print + ((int)eHart));

            People sInnes;
            sInnes = People.Innes;
            Console.WriteLine(sInnes + print + ((int)sInnes));

            People eJack;
            eJack = People.Jack;
            Console.WriteLine(eJack + print + ((int)eJack));

            People eMacGhee;
            eMacGhee = People.MacGhee;
            Console.WriteLine(eMacGhee + print + ((int)eMacGhee));

            People eMartindale;
            eMartindale = People.Martindale;
            Console.WriteLine(eMartindale + print + ((int)eMartindale));

            People sOlson;
            sOlson = People.Olson;
            Console.WriteLine(sOlson + print + ((int)sOlson));

            People ePachev;
            ePachev = People.Pachev;
            Console.WriteLine(ePachev + print + ((int)ePachev));

            People ePincoock;
            ePincoock = People.Pincoock;
            Console.WriteLine(ePincoock + print + ((int)ePincoock));

            People ePotter;
            ePotter = People.Potter;
            Console.WriteLine(ePotter + print + ((int)ePotter));

            People sReed;
            sReed = People.Reed;
            Console.WriteLine(sReed + print + ((int)sReed));

            People eSchaumann;
            eSchaumann = People.Schaumann;
            Console.WriteLine(eSchaumann + print + ((int)eSchaumann));

            People sSlocumbe;
            sSlocumbe = People.Slocumbe;
            Console.WriteLine(sSlocumbe + print + ((int)sSlocumbe));

            People sSoucie;
            sSoucie = People.Soucie;
            Console.WriteLine(sSoucie + print + ((int)sSoucie));

            People sThomson;
            sThomson = People.Thomson;
            Console.WriteLine(sThomson + print + ((int)sThomson));

            People sVeehar;
            sVeehar = People.Veehar;
            Console.WriteLine(sVeehar + print + ((int)sVeehar));

            People eWalch;
            eWalch = People.Walch;
            Console.WriteLine(eWalch + print + ((int)eWalch));

            People eWilson;
            eWilson = People.Wilson;
            Console.WriteLine(eWilson + print + ((int)eWilson));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что программа не работает?

Comment: Потому что на консоли она не выводиться должным образом. Так как было задумано. Я использую Visual Studio

Comment: как было задумано и как выводится сейчас?

Comment: @Grundy , зачем издеваешься? Все мы когда то не понимали основ. Нужно просто объяснить, что такие вопросы задавать очень не красиво, и нужно читать книги. (Хотя бы metanit.com).
п.с. возможно это синьйор тролит ребят. Первый вопрос он задал 8 ноября 2016 года. 2.5 года стажа, приличный стаж.

Comment: @AlexanderBrattsev, в чем заключается издевательство?

Comment: @Grundy, хм.. хотя, да, возможно это один из методов обучения. Причем - эффективный. Думать самому, доходить до ответа самому. Анализировать ошибки консоли, искать ответ в документации а не на stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

На сколько я понимаю твоя проблема в том, что тебе нужно использовать словарь вместо enum. То есть ты, банально, неправильно используешь энам потому, что не понимаешь для чего он вообще и как им пользоватся.

Да и сам последующий код метода Main ты дупо раздублировал.

Работающий вариант будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
namespace learnCS.orgProjectEnum2
{
    class Program
    {
        static dictionary<string, int> peopleDict = new dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            //здесь заполняй значения
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> human in peopleDict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{human.Key}'s Russian fluency rate is {human.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

код я, конечно же, не проверял и писал от балды, но это правильное направление того, что ты хочешь сделать.

Comment: Объясни пожалуйста каким образом я дублировал код метода Main?

Comment: тот код что у меня в мейн равен всему твоему коду в мейн. У кого меньше строк и в сколько раз? :)

Comment: п.с. метод типа не может обратиться к члену класса без экземпляра этого класса

Comment: проблема в том что дикшинари был динамичным.